# LinearSVC fails to use mean-difference to make classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have two sets of patterns, in which there is a patch where the mean value differs significantly between the two patterns (given by t-test [values are t-vals]). Here, the mean of the first set is **1±0.1** and the mean for the second is **2±0.1**, giving a **mean difference of about 1.**

[image]

I am trying to run a "searchlight" classifier across the grid to identify this patch using pattern classification, rather than t-tests on each pixel. The searchlight moves around the grid, trains and tests a unique classifier (LinearSVC) on the values from each 3x3 square of pixels. So, there is some "bleedover" which is fine and to be expected.

[image]

However, when I increase the means to **5±0.1** and **6±0.1**, the searchlight classifier fails pretty badly, even though the **mean difference is still about 1**.

[image]

1) Why would this classifier ever fail to use mean difference to make its discrimination?

2) Why does this work for a mean difference of 1 when the means are small, but fail to work when the means are slightly higher?

Comment: You are asking a question about a method very specific to neuroimaging, so you really need to explain the method a lot better in order for people to sit down and take a look at what is up. The best way to do this would be to post a minimal code example which is fully executable and generates the plots you show.

Comment: FWIW, for inspiration, there is a python implementation [here](https://github.com/nilearn/nilearn/blob/master/examples/decoding/plot_haxby_searchlight.py), and the [doc is here](http://nilearn.github.io/modules/generated/nilearn.decoding.SearchLight.html)

Comment: [This](https://github.com/nilearn/nilearn/blob/master/nilearn/decoding/searchlight.py#L34) is where the main action is.

Comment: As a first step to debugging, could you please run your code using not `LinearSVC`, but `SVC(kernel="linear")`. This may be due to a known issue with LibLinear (although I thought this only pertained to logistic regression)

Comment: @eickenberg, thanks -- the issue isn't with the searchlight, but with the classifier's handing of unnormalized means. Can you point me to the known issue with LibLinear? As soon as I switched to that, it looked like I expected.

Comment: OK, I wrote an answer explaining my guess of what is happening. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this problem may be due to an implementation detail of `LibLinear`: The sklearn estimators `LogisticRegression`, `LinearSVC` and `LinearSVR` are based on this library and all seem to share the same "feature":

The penalty `1 / C` is not only applied to the estimated weight vectors, but also to the intercept. This means that data that lie far away from the origin can become difficult to classify, even if the point clouds are perfectly separable: The intercept simply isn't set at the right place and tends to be pulled towards zero. In your particular case, if the intercept is pulled below the value of the lower activation, then classification will stop working.

There are several ways out of this, with advantages and disadvantages:

1) Choose a very low penalty for `LinearSVC`, e.g. `LinearSVC(C=1000)` (or `C` higher)

2) Use `SVC(kernel="linear")` and fall into the typical kernel methods issue of high sample complexity (i.e. this will be at least quadratic, probably cubic in the number of samples)

3) Center your data before using the estimator, e.g. with `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler`